# Creating an image of a drive cloned with ddrescue.

Tags: clone, virtualization, rescue, dd

We have an old server with disk failures that we've tried to clone into VMSphere. This resulted in an error from what that error came from we couldn't pin point.

With ddrescue we cloned the machine to a 2TB external hard drive that we can use to lab around with without having any downtime.

Then we used normal dd to try to create an image that we then later could convert or insert into the virtual environment.

Problem is that we have don't have any workstations that are able to handle a 2TB file. Is there any way that we can create an image of the drive with the partitions, data and mbr? Basically everything except for the unallocated space.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using "dd". If you have some idea how big the OS and data partitions were, just chop that much plus a bit extra off the front of the image and save in a new file. Say you guess it was 4GB of OS and 8GB of data, do something like this:

```
dd if=yourimage of=newsmallerimage bs=1024k count=14000
```

which will get you around 14GB. Any Virtual Machine will likely ignore any blank space at the end anyway.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, could you please accept it as the answer. If not, please let us know what happened so we can try and help further.